# Can not get valid product of IAP in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

I'm trying to add an in-app purchases for my App,

I've added a product in iTunes-Connect, and its status is Ready to Submit now.

But I can not get the valid product in function

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    NSLog(@"%@", response.invalidProductIdentifiers);
    if(myProduct.count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:myProduct[0]];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

the array of product is always empty, is there any step I miss?

My tax info is not finished for some reasons, is there realtionship with the problem?

Comment: is your product ID defined in viewDidLoad? paste your code for IAP

Comment: Defined, @Done `-(void)getProductInfo
{
    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"com.coins.test"]];
    
    SKProductsRequest *req = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:set];
    req.delegate = self;
    [req start];
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you test it on a real Apple TV (connected via USB) and not on the simulator!

That was my problem on not getting valid product IDs.